# LibGDX - Set a background image ( to be static)

Tags: java, libgdx, orthographic

I set the background image like this -

`batch.draw(Assets.back_sprite, 0, 0, ResX, ResY);`

The problem is when i move the camera -

`camera.translate(2,0);`

The image starting to move backwards and eventually disappears, because I drew it at (0,0)
and the camera is moving in a speed of (2,0), that's why the the image goes away.

- The camera is ortho not perspective.

How can i make the image to be static and always stay there?
Any ideas?

Thanks in advance :P

Comment: Render it with another camera.

Comment: Wow, its possible? can u answer me with some code and i will accept, how can i render two cameras in the same time its not possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Render it with another camera

```
OrthographicCamera mStageCamera;
OrthographicCamera mFixedCamera;
SpriteBatch mBatch;

@Override
public void render() {
    mBatch.setProjectionMatrix(mFixedCamera.combined);
    mBatch.begin();
    //render "static" elements
    mBatch.end();

    mBatch.setProjectionMatrix(mStageCamera.combined);
    mBatch.begin();
    //render "movable" elements
    mBatch.end();
}
```